# How to make a form resize vertically and horizontally when a control grows?

Tags: .net, winforms, layout, resize

(WinForms .net 2.0)

I'm making a form which, much like the standard `MessageBox`, has a single label on it and should grow horizontally and vertically if the text on the label grows. Horizontal seems easy enough, by setting `AutoSize = true` on the label and the form. However, I also want to make the label grow vertically, ie if it has newlines, but this doesn't seem so straightforward. I'm sure it is, but what settings are needed so that the label and form will grow vertically? I've got my label set to `Anchor = top, left, right, bottom`, so I'd have thought that when text with newlines is set in the label the height of the label will increase, and since `Anchor = top & bottom` it will force the form to increase in height. This doesn't seem to happen. What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

set `Autosize=True` and `AutoSizeMode=GrowAndShrink` on the form. Also make sure your controls will auto size to their content, and don't anchor to all four sides.

Comment: why not anchor to all four sides?

Comment: in the test I did, anchoring to all four sides prevented the form from resizing correctly.  I can send you the example if you would like.